# How to get a value from another HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to design a website which you can access with a QR code at restaurant and order your meal with that. I have a main page which you can see the menu. Each food has a button which opens a payment page. The payment page has some inputs like credit card informations, table number and telephone number. There are also two inputs which are disabled. These inputs are for the food name and price which we want to order. I want to fill these disabled inputs automatically by the clicking "order" button from the first HTML page. There are 6 different foods and all of them has different prices. How can I get the values of the name and price of the food to the second HTML's inputs, from the first HTML's texts?

**First HTML**

```
<div class="u-container-layout u-valign-middle u-container-layout-2">
    <h4 class="u-text u-text-3">Double Burger</h4>
    <h6 class="u-text u-text-palette-2-light-1 u-text-4">85.90₺</h6>
    <a href="payment.html" class="order"> Order </a>
</div>
```

**Second HTML**

```
<div class="form-body">
    <label for="orderedFood"> Ordered Food: </label>
    <input type="text" name="orderedFood" class="ordered-food" disabled/>
    <br>
    <label for="oderedFoodsPrice"> Price: </label>
    <input type="text" name="orderedFoodsPrice" class="ordered-foods-price" disabled/>
    <br>
</div>
```

I want to fill the inputs orderedFood and orderedFoodsPrice with the texts of food name and price by clicking the order button. I will also use these two inputs for a Mysqli table. The restaurant owner will see the order at Mysqli table. I would be very happy if you can help for that too but my priority is transfering the values.

Comment: This isn't your website? The answer is ... you can't - re-reading the question again ... this is your website, so, you can I guess - research `<form>` element

Comment: `from the first HTML's texts`...you don't. From the first page you should arrange it so that user submits the product ID(s) of the food they want to to order. your php code, when it receives that information, then fetches the name (and optionally any other useful fields), and the price information associated with the product(s) from the database on your server (taking into account any discounts, promotions etc if need be before displaying). If you let the price value be sent from the client-side and re-used by your code, then you are letting malicious users alter the price, if they want to.

Comment: Also...when the user initially submits their order from the first page, you should create an order record in the DB, which associates the user, and the product(s) they ordered. That way when you get to the payment page, you can easily retrieve everything associated with that specific order, and show it on the screen. Finally when the user starts the payment process, they just submit the order ID back again in the form (in a hidden field, I'd expect) and the server-side will handle passing the price payable to the payment processing server, so that - again - the client-side cannot alter it.

Comment: I think you need to sit down and re-think the design of this substantially, as you don't seem to have considered some fairly fundamental things, and/or don't have sufficient knowledge of PHP/HTML/SQL design basics to understand what might be needed. Bit concerned that you appear to be trying to design something which will ultimately try to take people's money, with (seemingly) barely even beginner-level skills in the relevant areas. I suggested working alongside a developer with experience of this sort of thing. Or, find an existing tool which covers this scenario already, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

In the first HTML anchor tag add price and food name as quesry search param.

#### First HTML

```
<div class="u-container-layout u-valign-middle u-container-layout-2">
    <h4 class="u-text u-text-3">Double Burger</h4>
    <h6 class="u-text u-text-palette-2-light-1 u-text-4">85.90₺</h6>
    <a href="payment.html" class="order"> Order </a>
</div>
```

With the help of Vanilla JS, Get the values from search param and set the input values.

#### Second HTML

```
<div class="form-body">
        <label for="orderedFood"> Ordered Food: </label>
        <input type="text" name="orderedFood" class="ordered-food" disabled />
        <br>
        <label for="oderedFoodsPrice"> Price: </label>
        <input type="text" name="orderedFoodsPrice" class="ordered-foods-price" disabled />
        <br>
    </div>


    <script>
        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const productName = urlParams.get('productName');
        const productPrice = urlParams.get('productPrice');

        // Fill the input fields with the values
        const orderedFoodInput = document.querySelector('.ordered-food');
        const orderedFoodPriceInput = document.querySelector('.ordered-foods-price');

        orderedFoodInput.value = productName;
        orderedFoodPriceInput.value = productPrice;
    </script>
```

Note: When the page loads with the provided query parameters, the input fields with the class names ordered-food and ordered-foods-price will be populated with the corresponding values.

Comment: Note: While this may appear to be functional, it is a naive approach which is highly vulnerable to knowledgeable users modifying the price to whatever they want before submitting the data. See comments on the main thread.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work...

Comment: @Quarinal it doesn't matter...it's not a sensible approach anyway. Did you read my comments under your question?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I read. I'm a student and this is my project. I have a very limited knowledge about HTML, CSS, JS and PHP. This is the best think which I could. I understand what do you mean but I guess I don't have enough knowledge for that. It doesn't need to be safe (for now) because our teacher didn't teach us that much thing. We only know some simple things about PHP. So I need a simple solution that will work for me now. Our goal is not to make websites that work perfectly. Our aim is to present a functional job, at least roughly, with our limited knowledge.

Comment: @Quarinal Ok. But at least they should have taught how to use a HTML form to send data from one page to another then? Otherwise you are not even prepared for making a basic version of this functionality.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I have a really bad teacher.

Comment: @Quarinal even if they didn't teach every detail, they need to at least introduce the important concepts so you are aware of where to start and what you need to research

Comment: @ADyson Unfortunately, I need to research and learn everything myself. I transferred it with sessionStorage but it takes the values from inputs, not from my h4 and h6 texts and it looks awful with inputs at the first HTML page. I need to fix that now.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the pricing you need to send the data to the database using `POST` request and use it wherever you want to by making a `GET` request to the appropriate endpoint.

another way of doing this is you redirect to the page where you want to use this data by sending it as query params

Comment: `query params` or use some form of local storage unless you need to support browsers from over 10 years ago

Comment: local storage would be good fit in this scenario

Answer (score -2):

Change your

```
<a href="payment.html" class="order"> Order </a>
```

to

```
<a href="payment.html" class="order" onclick="preprocessOrder(this)"> Order </a>
```

and implement `preprocessOrder`. Example

## HTML

```
<div class="u-container-layout u-valign-middle u-container-layout-2">
    <h4 class="u-text u-text-3">Double Burger</h4>
    <h6 class="u-text u-text-palette-2-light-1 u-text-4">85.90₺</h6>
    <a href="payment.html" class="order" target="_blank" onclick="preprocessOrder(this);"> Order </a>
</div>
```

## JS

```
function preprocessOrder(context) {
    context.href = `payment.html?text=${context.parentNode.querySelector('h4').innerText}&price=${context.parentNode.querySelector('h6').innerText}`;
}
```

## JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wx3uh1ev/

## The second page

The second page receives the information as GET parameters, so you will need to infer these values via PHP, so you will need to make sure your second page is a PHP file or some other template that is able to display GET parameter values.